# finding the cdf of $f_{(X,Y)}(x, y) = e^{−x} \ \text{for} \ 0 \leq y \leq x < \infty,$

Tags: probability

How do you find the cdf of this?

$$f_{(X,Y)}(x, y) = e^{−x} \ \text{for} \  0 \leq y \leq x < \infty,$$

I have tried:

$$F_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = \int^{\infty}_{0}\int^{x}_{0}{e^{-x}}dydx$$

integrate by parts

$$F_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = [-xe^{-x} - e^{-x}]^{\infty}_{0}$$

which will give me

$$F_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = 1$$

which is wrong as the solution is

F(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{x<0, y<0} \\[2ex]
1-e^{-y}-ye^{-x}, & \text{0 ≤ y ≤ x}\\[2ex]
1-e^{-x}-xe^{-y}, & \text{y > x ≥ 0}
\end{cases}

I don't understand how they came to that answer and how they got those bounds, especially the y > x ≥ 0 because the question states that x≥y.

Comment: You started with the wrong expression for the CDF.

Comment: what should the correct expression for the CDF be to start with?

Comment: CDF by definition is $P(X\le x,Y\le y)$. So what is the corresponding integral? See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238660/find-the-distribution-function-of-bivariate-distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You are using $x$ with two different meanings. $x$ and $y$ on LHS should not be mixed with variables of integration on RHS.  You should write $F_{(X,Y)}(u,v)=\int_0^{u}\int_0^{min(x,v)} e^{-x} dy dx$. I hope you can carry out the integration now.